# How to use math operation in an array index created by the package arrayjob

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, multido, arrayjob

I want to put each number in the array on a grid using `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multido}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\newarray\Values
\readarray{Values}{I&F&I&G&L&O&C&K&E&D&A&W&A&Y&.}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid(5,3);
  %     \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
  %         \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
  %         {
  %             \node at (\x-0.5,\y-0.5) {\Values(\x+\y*5)};
  %         }
    \multido{\dx=0cm+1cm,\iColumn=1+1}{5}{%
        \multido{\dy=0cm+1cm,\iRow=1+2}{3}{%
        \node at (\dx+0.5cm,\dy+0.5cm) {\Values(\iColumn+\iRow*5)};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got something like this. The result is similar if I replace `\multido` with `\foreach`. Math operation seems not to be supported in the index of the array. How can I fix this please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `arrayjobx`, but it doesn't support arithmetic on its arguments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multido}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\Values
\readarray{Values}{I&F&I&G&L&O&C&K&E&D&A&W&A&Y&.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid(5,3);
      \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
        {
          \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
            {
              \node at (\x-0.5,\y-0.5) {\expandafter\Values\expandafter(\the\numexpr\x+\y*5)};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

More easily, define a command that does the job:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multido}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\Values
\readarray{Values}{I&F&I&G&L&O&C&K&E&D&A&W&A&Y&.}

\newcommand{\Get}[2]{%
  \expandafter#1\expandafter(\the\numexpr#2\relax)%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid(5,3);
      \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
        {
          \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
            {
              \node at (\x-0.5,\y-0.5) {\Get\Values{\x+\y*5}};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With more modern tools:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_jasmine_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_jasmine_array_#1_seq } { & } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getarrayitem}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { l_jasmine_array_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{Values}{I&F&I&G&L&O&C&K&E&D&A&W&A&Y&.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid(5,3);
      \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
        {
          \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
            {
              \node at (\x-0.5,\y-0.5) {\getarrayitem{Values}{\x+\y*5}};
            }
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All three pieces of code yield the same result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! They really help. Actually, I have tackled it before with a 2-d array by the command \dataheight=5 so I can get the value by the command \Values(\y,\x)

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \graph[
    grid placement, wrap after=5, branch up,
    fresh nodes, nodes={
      draw, minimum size=+1cm, text height=+\ht\strutbox, text depth=+0pt},
  ]{I, F, I, G, L, O, C, K, E, D, A, W, A, Y, .};

\tikz
  \draw (0,0) grid (5,3) [shift={(.5,.5)}]
    graph[
      grid placement, wrap after=5, branch up,
      fresh nodes, nodes={text height=+\ht\strutbox, text depth=+0pt},
    ]{I, F, I, G, L, O, C, K, E, D, A, W, A, Y, .};

\tikz
  \node foreach[count=\i from 0] \t in {I, F, I, G, L, O, C, K, E, D, A, W, A, Y, .}
    [draw, minimum size=+1cm, text height=+\ht\strutbox, text depth=+0pt]
      at ({mod(\i,5)},{int(\i/5)}) {\t};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]